# Alert users according to their saved search terms via email

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to alert users based on their saved search term. So, I have alerts table where users id and terms are stored. For example:

`ID: 1 | uid: 27 | emailSentAt: null | search: Adidas`

`ID: 2 | uid: 27 | emailSentAt: null | search: Samsung`

`ID: 3 | uid: 34 | emailSentAt: null | search: Pro Evolution Soccer 2017`

When user searches something it is read from campaigns table. For the simplicity, lets say it has id and search (VARCHAR) field.

What I want is to alert user (according to their stored search term) every time when new campaign is added related to that term. It doesn't have to be automatically. I can do it manually, and I've tried something like this...
This is a function from `Mailable` class:

```
    public function build()
        {
            echo "Sending email alert...\n";
            $user = DB::table('alerts')->select('*')
            ->join('users', 'alerts.uid', '=', 'users.id')->whereNotNull('search')->get();

            return $this->view('emails.newSearchAlert', compact('user'));
        }
```

And from `Command` class:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $when = Carbon::now();
        $user = DB::table('alerts')->select('search', 'email')
        ->join('users', 'alerts.uid', '=', 'users.id')->whereNotNull('search')->get();
        foreach ($user as $u) {
            Mail::to($u->email)->later($when, new NewAlertsEmail);
        }
        echo "All email alerts are sent.";
    }
```

And when I run the command `php artisan email:users`, it sends emails with all search terms to all users.
My question is: How can I manage to get query result to display in a view something like this:

`<h1>New campaigns are available for your search terms: {{ $user->search }}: </h1>
<img src="http:/mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/{{ $campaign->search }}.png">`

Btw. I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: assuming your emails are html, just pass the results array through and echo the row values required

Comment: Yeah, but how can I assure that each user gets emails referred only to their search. Like I've said. Now, every user gets every search term. For example, user with id 34 gets all: `Adidas, Samsung, PES 2017` even though he/she saved only PES.

Comment: You can do it one of two ways - Either a fresh query for each email that only gets the relevant tags, or a single query that provides the array that you search for the relevant tags in.

Comment: I've tried a couple of things but no luck. Actually, I don't know how to use the `where` clause in this case so I could send each term to specified user.